# jQuery: Anything Slider - Multiple Sliders - Reset other sliders to first slide?

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I'm using Anythingslider to show 3 x sliders on one page.

Each slider is within a tab...e.g. click "Tab 1" - Slider 1 will show, click "Tab 2" Slider 2 will show etc etc...

Trouble is, slides are not reset on each tab..e.g. if i'm on "Tab 1" and viewing slide 3, then I click on "Tab 2" and  then back to "Tab 1" - it's still on slide 3 - not reset to slide 1....

So my question is how can I reset the slides back to one, when click viewing other tabs?

It's almost like you need a jquery version of the following:

```
IF you click an <li class="tab"> then reset all sliders to slide 1..
```

Anyhoo, someone may have a better idea? Hope someone can assist?

Comment: Have you tried setting the sliders to the first slide on the tab click event - $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(0);

Comment: Got an example how to use this when you click  <li class="tab"> ?

Comment: Without knowing what your HTML looks like or what tab code you are using, if it has callbacks etc, I think @SagarPatil has the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tab').click(function(){
        $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(0);
    });

});
```

You can also use set your other click actions for '.tab' by binding them to the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tab').bind("click", function(){
        $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(0);
        // other .tab click actions
    });

});
```

Comment: This should work, except that AnythingSlider uses a 1-based index, so change it to `.anythingSlider(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/8/)

this example handles manual navigation of slides in `AnythingSlider`, you can navigate to the first slide if you want to reset the sliders when click the `li` element

Comment: I'm using external navigation... which works fine..but that is within a tab....so really it needs applying to the tab... got a code example how to add the reset function "<li class="tab">" ?